# Google Cloud Endpoints return value from a method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

How can I return a value (i.e. boolean, string, etc.) from either an @endpoint.method or a @MyModel.method (EndpointsModel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, you cannot write simple types like String, int, etc. The return types will need to be a POJO, an array or a Collection.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types

Comment: Perhaps this is a different question, but what would be a solution for implementing "return boolean"-type behavior? Return an empty array for true, return null for false?

Comment: @opowell: you could create a wrapper class around a Boolean as follow and return a wrapper instance.     public static class WrappedBoolean {

        private final Boolean booleanResponse;

        public WrappedBoolean(Boolean b) {
            booleanResponse = b;
        }

        public Boolean getBooleanResponse() {
            return booleanResponse;
        }
    }